# Does filter length correspond to "spread" of frequency points?

Tags: finite-impulse-response

[Here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch17/1.htm) it's given that to design an arbitrary response filter one can design such filter by "drawing" the response to an array of some length. It's also given that:

> This ideal frequency response is defined by an array of numbers that have been selected, not some mathematical equation. In this example, there are 513 samples spread between 0 and 0.5 of the sampling rate.

Now since it says that

> 513 samples spread between 0 and 0.5 of the sampling rate.

then does this mean that the length of the filter corresponds to the "spread" of frequency points in the frequency range [0, 0.5*samplingrate]?

Comment: If you read on, you'll find this: "[...] This results in a 1024 sample signal running from 0 to 1023, as shown in (b). This is the impulse response that corresponds to the frequency response we want; however, it is not suitable for use as a filter kernel (more about this shortly). Just as in the last chapter, it needs to be shifted, truncated, and windowed." So yes, you get an impulse response of length 1024, but then you window it to the desired length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "spread" you mean "number of samples".

The filter length, or number of taps, is not necessarily related to the number of frequency samples.

If you generate the filter by frequency sampling, it is. If you interpolate between desired frequency response samples, you can generate arbitrary length filters using the frequency sampling method. Also, if you generate a filter using optimization; then filter length and number of frequency samples are independent of each other.

As a general rule of thumb: more taps means better approximation to the desired response.